# How to extract string after period (.) using regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript

if my string is like this -

```
"this is the .string .needed to .be .tested"
```

i need to extract these strings - "string" "needed" "be" "tested"
I need only using RegExp but not any other string operations

Comment: Use RegEx [`/\.(\S+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/aK1aI0/1) with `exec()`. Here's the [**code**](https://regex101.com/r/aK1aI0/1#code_1)

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried, even if not working.

Comment: Array[2]
0
:
".string"
1
:
"string"
index
:
12
input
:
"this is the .string .needed to .be .tested"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]

Comment: that is the o/p i got.

Comment: Is it possible to get all the matched strings in a single array @tushar

Comment: You can even do it without regex here is an example 
``str.split('.')`` that gives you an array of strings that you can manipulate as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

as Tushar said in the comment, you can use `exec` to do this stuff, something like the following:

```
var regEx = /\.(\S+)/g;
var text = "this is the .string .needed to .be .tested";
var words = [];
while (word = regEx.exec(text)) {
   words.push(word[1]);
}
console.log(words);
```

Comment: What if we make period as dynamic variable.. for example i pass underscore"_" it should match string next to _ and return the string. if i pass character "s" the same should happen as of "." @aguardientico

Comment: What if we make period as dynamic variable.. for example i pass underscore"_" it should match string next to _ and return the string. if i pass character "s" the same should happen as of "."

Comment: can we get the same output by creating new RegExp object.

Comment: Is this correct var regEx =  new RegExp("[.](\S+)", "g");

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\.(\w+)/` to match `.` followed by word, `.slice()` with parameter `1` to remove `.` character

```
var str = "this is the .string .needed to .be .tested";
var res = []; 
str.replace(/\.(\w+)/g, function(match) {
  res.push(match.slice(1))
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` function

```js
var str = "this is the .string .needed to .be .tested";

var res = str.match(/\.\S+/g).map(e => e.substr(1));

document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```